# Why use ObservableCollection.Clear() but the GC didn't work

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, garbage-collection, observablecollection

I have a ObservableCollection which binding to a listbox in the Pivot, when i used the method Clear(). It seems to the GC didn't recycle. So when i keep Clearing the ObservableCollection, the memory keep incresing. Any one know why this happened?

Comment: I don't know a bit about Silverlight, but generally: Calling a method like `Clear` won't force the GC to run, it will just remove a few references. The absence of those references may allow the GC to collect more objects *when* it runs - but when (and strictly speaking, even *whether it runs at all*) it runs is neither under your control (ignoring `System.GC()` or whatever it's called, which is almost always a bad idea anyway) nor should it be your concern. What period of time and what memory consumption are we taking about?

Comment: Also, clearing references from a list, won't necessary kill them, unless you're absolutely certain they're not referenced any other place. Besides, there are bigger things to concern about, when regarding performance, than a simple listbox.

Comment: I understand what you are talking about of the GC.But i still have a problem.I am writting a WP7 App now.And the MainPage has a Pivot which have seven PivotItem.Each PivotItem has a listbox which binding to ObservableCollection. When i navigate from MainPage, I clear the ObservableCollection.But when I back from other page to the MainPage, the memory decrease a little. If I navigate from the MainPage many times,the memory will go over the WP7 app memory limit.How can deal with the problem?

Comment: @Joel - are you still having a problem with this? If so, can I suggest you submit a new question that clarifies the real issue at hand? Fundamentally, you don't (and shouldn't have to) care when garbage collection runs, you care that you are running out of memory. Do I have that correctly? The question title you've got is not going to get you the answer you need. Just a thought. Meanwhile, I'll give a thought to your problem. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Garbage collection on WP7 behaves differently from other .Net garbage collectors.  It's programmed only to run when memory usage exceeds a specific level.

Also, keep in mind that the garbage collector has changed in Mango:  In the original WP7 the garbage collector was non-generational, in Mango it is now generational.

If you're desperate to clear down memory then GC.Collect() (Windows Phone 7) 
or GC.Collect(3) (Windows Phone 7 Mango only)

will be what you're after.  Doing this will pause the application so it makes sense to do this where the user will accept a pause - probably just after you change screens or save data are good times to do this.